# Turn WiFi off using Python on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, wifi

I have been looking for a way to toggle my wifi on and off using a script. I figured this could be done maybe by entering airplane mode or some other method. When I was googleing for the answer though I could not find anything useful for windows, just for android and even macOS.

Anyone have a 2 functions, one for turning wifi off, and one for turning it back on? Or connecting/disconnecting from a specific one works too. It is my default wifi if this is relevant.

Comment: Have you tried doing a system call to PowerShell? `subprocess.check_output` with [some goodies here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/24/use-powershell-to-disable-wi-fi/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python does not have direct access to your Wifi Adapter but windows does. 
So you can use `os` module to run commmand prompt codes and control your wifi adapter.

1. Get the interface name
2. Then you can just use the name to run on/off commands

   ```
   # Get the interface name using this script.
   import os 
   os.system("netsh interface show interface")
   ```

Then replace it with `Wifi` in this script to get going.

```
import os 
def enable():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Wifi' enabled")

def disable():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Wifi' disabled")
```

Comment: My wifi is "Wi-Fi 2" when I enter it in there it says 2 is not an acceptable value for admin. Somehow it is taking the 2, in wifi 2 as input? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: maybe you are not putting it in proper quotes , so it is considering it as 2 distinct values.

Comment: if that doesn't work , maybe you can try changing the interface name to a single word.

Comment: Got it like this: "netsh interface set interface 'Wi-Fi 2' disabled" is that not correct quotes? Pretty sure this is right.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get "The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator)." -> How can I solve this?

Comment: @robrados : Open  a command prompt with administer access. then run the script from that prompt.

Comment: This does not work, even when running in command line on Windows 10. I get "No more data is available" in reply.

Comment: same as @InvestingTS. btw I have tried making interface name single word.

Answer (score 3):

```
os.system(f'netsh {iface_type} connect {iface_name}')

os.system(f'netsh {iface_type} disconnect')
```

updated netsh wifi commands for 2022 for anyone who needs them

Answer (score 0):

netsh interface set interface name = "Wi-fi" enabled

netsh interface set interface name = "Wi-fi" disabled

Just replace ' with "

You need administrator rights to use this command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is take the space out and it works for me.

For example: use `interface name = "Wi-Fi2"` with the code above.