# Is there any function in selenium that closes internet connection and resumes after specific amount of time?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate a situation wherein I need to close internet connection of device and then resume it again. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246527/turn-wifi-off-using-python-on-windows-10 You may be able to adapt this for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a large amount of code after this incident situation? You can use mocks, to handle it.
Or if the downtime is the same, you can just put wait.

```
time.sleep(downtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it operating system is ubuntu :
1. Launch terminal using 'os' module in python and shut down networking interface
    command : os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'sudo ifconfig eth0 down'")
2. Do your required task
3. Again, make network interface up and running
    command : os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'sudo ifconfig eth0 up'")